# Add 'Recent activity' menu next to 'Recent inbox' and 'Recent achievements'

Tags: feature-request

I often want to find my most recent qustions answers or comments, for review purposes or to check how many views did it gain.

I find myself go to the browser's history, or filter the Q&A in my profile in order to find them.

I suggest an icon next to 'Recent inbox' and 'Recent achievements' where a set of my recent activities is accessible easily.

[image]

Comment: This would be very cool to have. Note that the "achievements" tab can sort of be used to do this as long as your posts get votes.

Comment: I'm often interested in my posts that did not get any special attention (no votes or comments). It just might mean they need to be improved...

Comment: Agreed (though that doesn't happen very often for me, I usually get *some* feedback). Like I said, would love to see this feature happen.